# center object with css

Tags: html, css, navbar

this is a html/css nav bar how can i center it in the center of my page i tryed putting center tags in the html and float:center; under the ul but it wont work ill post my html then my css

HTML

```
<body>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">&nbsp;</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
```

CSS

```
ul
{
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
overflow:hidden;
}
li
{
float:left;
}
a:link,a:visited
{
display:block;
width:120px;
font-weight:bold;
color:#FFFFFF;
background-color:#98bf21;
text-align:center;
padding:4px;
text-decoration:none;
text-transform:uppercase;
}
a:hover,a:active
{
background-color:#7A991A;
}
```

Comment: noobish question sorry

Comment: Hate work with HTML only for this problem. P.S. you will get answer faster if create http://jsfiddle.net ;)

Comment: cant use that site my antivirus blocked it for some reason theres no way to unblock it unless i pull hosts file theres thousnds of them tho

Comment: i dont know what you're asking, but if this is what you're trying to achieve... http://jsfiddle.net/4sEJH/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add text-align: center to ul and replace float: left with display: inline-block

```
ul
{
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
overflow:hidden;
text-align:center; <<add this
}
li
{
display:inline-block; << add this instead of float
}
```

The other parts of your css remains unchanged!

So if You add more li to your website they'll all be in the center next to each other.

```
<li><a href="#">&nbsp;</a></li>
<li><a href="#">&nbsp;</a></li>
```

To remove the whitespace:

```
 <li><a href="#">&nbsp;</a></li><li><a href="#">&nbsp;</a></li>
```

Don't push enter between each line. :)

...or there's another solution is to add: margin-left:-4px:

```
   li
    {
display:inline-block; 
margin-left: -4px;
    }
```

Comment: thanks but on my page ill get white spaces like this look  http://gamecheats.herobo.com/

Comment: Put it into one line like this (and the white space should gone):

<li><a href="#">&nbsp;</a></li><li><a href="#">&nbsp;</a></li>

or You can add margin-left: -4px;
li {
display:inline-block;
margin-left:-4px;
}

Answer (score 2):

```
ul
{
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
overflow:hidden;
}
li
{
    padding-left:200px;

}
a:link,a:visited
{

display:block;
width:120px;
font-weight:bold;
color:#FFFFFF;
background-color:#98bf21;
text-align:center;
padding:4px;
text-decoration:none;
text-transform:uppercase;
}
a:hover,a:active
{
background-color:#7A991A;
}
```

[demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/8c7wm/)

Answer (score 1):

Put the `<ul>` inside a `<div>` and center it using `align="center"`

like this:

```
<div align="center">
<ul>
    <li>hhhh</li>
    <li>hhhhh</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add:

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

to the css for the ul and a elements, and remove the float: left; from the li.

See this [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/JYwRn/)

Comment: Well then, you'll have to add the float back, and set a width on the UL  See here http://jsfiddle.net/JYwRn/3/

Answer (score 1):

Since you give your `a` a `width: 120px` then why cannot give your ul the same property and using `margin`:

```
width: 120px;
margin: 0 auto;
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/NYE3y/

Answer (score 0):

Use an wrapper for UL and apply an width to wrapper

```
<div class="menu-wrap">
    <ul>
        <li>Menu A</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.menu-wrap {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:500px;
}
```

you can still use float for your li.
Remember to clear floats always.